# For loop in range output start from 0 to input i have tried everything

Tags: python

```
kertoma = int(input("Kuinka monta kierrosta?:"))

tulos = int(0)

for tulos in range(1, kertoma+1):
    tulos = tulos + kertoma
    print("Kertymäksi saatiin:", int(tulos))
```

so my question is, if i wanna put input as 3 it should do from 0+1+2 and the out put should be 3 but instead of 3 the output is 6 and if i want to input 5 it should be 0+1+2+3+4

Thanks in advance

Comment: thank you barmar :) im newbie at stackoverflow

Comment: Python has a built-in `sum()` function: `sum(range(kertoma))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be adding `kertoma` in the loop, you should be adding the iteration variable from the range.

You need to use a different variable for the iteration than the variable you're adding to.

You don't have to write `int(0)`, just `0`. And `tulos` is an integer, so you don't have to write `int(tulos)`.

The limit of the range should be `kertomas`, not `kertomas+1`, because `range()` doesn't include the end.

```
kertoma = int(input("Kuinka monta kierrosta?:"))

tulos = 0

for i in range(1, kertoma):
    tulos = tulos + i
    
print("Kertymäksi saatiin:", tulos)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
upper_limit = int(input("What's the upper limit? "))

total = 0

for num in range(upper_limit):
    total = total + num

print("The result is:", total)
```

Be aware that, for range calls, the upper limit is *excluded*: if you type 3 as the input, it will iterate three times (with num set to 0, 1, and 2) - having *upper_limit+1* as the argument of range will also include the upper_limit itself (which is why in your case the output was 6 instead of 3).